# How to put x-axis values

Tags: r

I want to put x-axis value as 2002 to 2011 to corresponding boxplot graph each displaying data from 2002 to 2011 individually. There must have some trick!

Code:

```
d = read.table("C:/sample.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE)
attach(d)
summary(d)
boxplot(2002, 2003,2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 
        data=d, boxcol="blue", medcol="red", whiskcol="blue", 
        staplecol="blue", ylim = c(0, 1), lty=1, las=1, ylab = "NDVI", 
        outline = FALSE, boxfill = FALSE)
```

Sample data

```
2002    2003    2004    2005    2006    2007    2008    2009    2010    2011
0.8392  0.8337  0.8145  0.8306  0.8545  0.7876  0.8491  0.8568  0.8459  0.8778
0.8251  0.7509  0.7301  0.7829  0.8103  0.7368  0.7122  0.685   0.7623  0.8159
0.8584  0.8217  0.8105  0.8295  0.8382  0.769   0.8265  0.8287  0.8344  0.8204
0.8651  0.8211  0.8346  0.8624  0.8629  0.7926  0.8543  0.8648  0.8456  0.8656
0.7991  0.7653  0.7512  0.8106  0.8354  0.7013  0.752   0.8256  0.8235  0.7579
0.8572  0.8186  0.8009  0.6988  0.719   0.7645  0.8142  0.8164  0.7529  0.7214
0.8483  0.8159  0.833   0.8401  0.8426  0.7777  0.8608  0.8243  0.8426  0.8602
```

Comment: I attempted to format your code so that it is readable, but your boxplot call looks like nonsense to me. Can you please check it and make sure it matches what you're actually running?

Comment: boxplot(2002, 2003,2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, data=d, boxcol="blue", medcol="red", whiskcol="blue", staplecol="blue", ylim = c(0, 1), lty=1, las=1, ylab = "NDVI", outline = FALSE, boxfill = FALSE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to `boxplot` is wrong.

See below.

```
> df <- read.table(textConnection('2002    2003    2004    2005    2006    2007    2008    2009    2010    2011
+ 0.8392  0.8337  0.8145  0.8306  0.8545  0.7876  0.8491  0.8568  0.8459  0.8778
+ 0.8251  0.7509  0.7301  0.7829  0.8103  0.7368  0.7122  0.685   0.7623  0.8159
+ 0.8584  0.8217  0.8105  0.8295  0.8382  0.769   0.8265  0.8287  0.8344  0.8204
+ 0.8651  0.8211  0.8346  0.8624  0.8629  0.7926  0.8543  0.8648  0.8456  0.8656
+ 0.7991  0.7653  0.7512  0.8106  0.8354  0.7013  0.752   0.8256  0.8235  0.7579
+ 0.8572  0.8186  0.8009  0.6988  0.719   0.7645  0.8142  0.8164  0.7529  0.7214
+ 0.8483  0.8159  0.833   0.8401  0.8426  0.7777  0.8608  0.8243  0.8426  0.8602'), header=TRUE)
> boxplot(df, names=2002:2011)
```

[image]

If you call `boxplot` with other parameters as specified in your example, you get following.

```
> boxplot(df, names=2002:2011, boxcol="blue",
          medcol="red", whiskcol="blue", staplecol="blue",
          ylim = c(0, 1), lty=1, las=1, ylab = "NDVI", 
          outline = FALSE, boxfill = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: @geektrader could you please advise me how to do that - i am new in this group.

Comment: @geektrader is there anyway to display 2002-2006 data with different background color and 2007 to 2011 with different background color?