# Colouring different group data in boxplot using r

Tags: r

[How to put x-axis values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060036/how-to-put-x-axis-values)

The Box-plot in the link, I want to display different background colour for example: 2002-2004 - in one group, 2005-2007 in another group while from 2008-2011 in another group. All groups could be displayed on different background colour with description of legend or notes at bottom on graphs.

How can I display those group boxplots in different colours (each group boxplot should be in same colour)?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 df <- read.table(textConnection('2002    2003    2004    2005    2006    2007    2008    2009    2010    2011
 0.8392  0.8337  0.8145  0.8306  0.8545  0.7876  0.8491  0.8568  0.8459  0.8778
 0.8251  0.7509  0.7301  0.7829  0.8103  0.7368  0.7122  0.685   0.7623  0.8159
 0.8584  0.8217  0.8105  0.8295  0.8382  0.769   0.8265  0.8287  0.8344  0.8204
 0.8651  0.8211  0.8346  0.8624  0.8629  0.7926  0.8543  0.8648  0.8456  0.8656
 0.7991  0.7653  0.7512  0.8106  0.8354  0.7013  0.752   0.8256  0.8235  0.7579
 0.8572  0.8186  0.8009  0.6988  0.719   0.7645  0.8142  0.8164  0.7529  0.7214
 0.8483  0.8159  0.833   0.8401  0.8426  0.7777  0.8608  0.8243  0.8426  0.8602'), header=TRUE)

#New code for coloring
colors = c(rep("red",3),rep("blue",3),rep("green",4))
boxplot(df, names=2002:2011,col=colors)
```

[image]

Comment: -thanks. How can I change the boarder and whisker color according to group. Can i put some dividing line in those groups using x axis?