# Adding colors in R for Boxplot

Tags: r

```
boxplot(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$cyl, main = "Box Plot of Mileage vs Number of Cylinders", xlab = "Number of Cylinders", ylab = "Miles per Gallon", col = "lightgreen")
```

I have this code and all the boxed are green, what can i add to this to make the boxes different colors

Comment: you can pass a vector of values in `col`  Here, there are 3 boxplots, so the number of colours can be 3. `boxplot(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$cyl, main = "Box Plot of Mileage vs Number of Cylinders", xlab = "Number of Cylinders", ylab = "Miles per Gallon", col = c("lightgreen", "red", "blue"))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Colouring different group data in boxplot using r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212884/colouring-different-group-data-in-boxplot-using-r)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a factor(x_axis_var) for color.

```
boxplot(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$cyl, 
        main = "Box Plot of Mileage vs Number of Cylinders", 
        xlab = "Number of Cylinders", 
        ylab = "Miles per Gallon", col = factor(mtcars$cyl))
```

or provide a vector of colors:

```
boxplot(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$cyl, 
        main = "Box Plot of Mileage vs Number of Cylinders", 
        xlab = "Number of Cylinders", 
        ylab = "Miles per Gallon", col = c("blue","red","green"))
```

Comment: Did this help you? Consider accepting the answer if it helped you.